# average range of data and plot in gnuplot

Tags: range, gnuplot, average, rows, calculated-columns

I have this kind of data:

```
label-> 1   2   3   4   5
val1    1.67E+07    2.20E+07    3.04E+07    7.89E+07    1.24E+08
val2    1.71E+07    2.35E+07    2.70E+07    7.80E+07    1.31E+08
val3    1.48E+07    2.15E+07    2.74E+07    7.18E+07    1.17E+08
val4    1.57E+07    2.07E+07    2.49E+07    7.46E+07    1.27E+08
val5    1.32E+07    2.23E+07    3.07E+07    7.50E+07    1.16E+08
```

I need to plot the label vs the average of each val column, like this:

```
label-> 1   2   3   4   5
val1    1.67E+07    2.20E+07    3.04E+07    7.89E+07    1.24E+08
val2    1.71E+07    2.35E+07    2.70E+07    7.80E+07    1.31E+08
val3    1.48E+07    2.15E+07    2.74E+07    7.18E+07    1.17E+08
val4    1.57E+07    2.07E+07    2.49E+07    7.46E+07    1.27E+08
val5    1.32E+07    2.23E+07    3.07E+07    7.50E+07    1.16E+08
mean    1.55E+07    2.20E+07    2.81E+07    7.57E+07    1.23E+08
```

Is there any possibility of perform this operation in gnuplot or should I keep attached to Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `awk` and `gnuplot`. Assume your example data (without `mean` row) is in `data.txt`.
Then you could calculate the mean in each column starting from the second column (from `i=2`) and the second row (record, or row, #1 -- `NR==1` -> do not summate, but fill auxiliary array `a` with zeroes: `a[i]=0.0`). For that purpose one could use `awk` condition: `if (NR==1)... else {...calculate the means...}`.
`Awk` reads the data row-by-row. In each row, you iterate over fields and summate the data from column with number `i` into array element `a[i]`:

```
{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i;}
```

When iterating over the first row (`NR==1`), we would  ;
At the `END` of `awk` script (all rows processed), just divide by number of columns in your data `NF-1` to calculate the mean values. Note, the code below assumes you have rectangular-formatted data (`NF`=const).

Also, save row column labels into `label` array:
`if (NR==1) {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) label[i]=$i; ... }`

Then print the labels and mean values into the rows, one row for one label.

```
for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {printf label[i]" "; print a[i]/(NF-1)}
```

The final data table would look that way:

```
1 15500000
2 22000000
3 28080000
4 75660000
5 123000000
```

Then you could plot one column against the other.
Note, the final data for gnuplot should be formatted in columns, not rows.
The following code performs the described operations:

```
gnuplot> unset key
gnuplot> plot "<export LC_NUMERIC=C; awk '{if (NR==1) {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) label[i]=$i; a[i]=0.0;} else {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i;};} END {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {printf label[i]\" \"; print a[i]/(NF-1)}};' data.txt"
```

Note, that spaces should be escaped with backslash character `\` in the `gnuplot`.